# Which SVN subversion can I use on linux, Mac, Windows?

Tags: linux, git, svn, tortoisesvn, cvs

Which SVN subversion can I use on linux (Ubuntu), Mac and Windows to store my projects in a repository. Is there any separate version control for linux? I searched for linux, but everybody suggests we should use different version control for linux. Please give some idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about subversion, or revision control in general? Your question is unclear and the many tags don't help clarify the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svn consists of a server and a client. The operating system the server runs on may differ from the os the client runs on (like a webserver  and a browser). For the different client OS there are different svn client implementations. Some of those run on only one OS some of them on all. A lot of IDEs (e.g. IntelliJ, Eclipse, ..) even bring their own SVN client. Some common svn clients are: trotoise (windows), smart svn (windows, linux, mac), svn command line (linux - use your favourite package manager).

If you are asking for an alternative to SVN (i.e. different Version Control) e.g. git comes in mind although it works quite differently. What you do not want is a different VCS for windows & linux, that makes absolulty no sense.